# How to apply a function to each 3rd axis element in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

If I have a numpy array like so:

```
[[[137 153 135]
  [138 154 136]
  [138 153 138]
  ..., 
  [134 159 153]
  [136 159 153]
  [135 158 152]]
  ...,
  [ 57  44  34]
  [ 55  47  37]
  [ 55  47  37]]]
```

How can I apply a function to each [000 000 000]  entry, modifying it?

```
# a = numpy array
for x in a:
    for y in x:
        y = modify(y)
```

What I'd like to achieve is modifying each (r,g,b) pixel in a PIL image that was converted to a numpy array.

Comment: What does `modify()` exactly do?  It is easy to give an answer to this question, but we can only give an *efficient* answer if we know what `modify()` does.

Comment: def modify(px):
 r,g,b = px
 if r == max(r,g,b) and r > 125 and g < 70 and b < 110:
  return (255,0,0)
 else:
  return (255,255,255)

Comment: There's a bracket missing, no?

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Comment: No, but it doesn't matter. Basically what I'd like to do is to make all red-ish colors red (255,0,0) and all others white (255,255,255).

Comment: @Sven: Why do we need to know what the `modify()` function does? That's not relevant, as you could `map()` (or use list comprehension) to apply any function.

Comment: @Rabarberski: It's relevant to give an efficient answer.  Just time the two versions given in my answer for an image of -- say -- 2000x2000 pixels.  You'll see the vectorised version is orders of magnitude faster.  Python loops over every single pixel are usually to slow for image processing.

Answer (score 5):

A simple answer to your question is

```
for row in a:
    for item in row:
        item[:] = modify(item)
```

This won't be very efficient, though.  An efficient solution should avoid Python loops over all pixels. (That's somehow what NumPy is all about -- vectorise your code!)  A vectorised version for the case at hand would be

```
r, g, b = a[..., 0], a[..., 1], a[..., 2]
new_a = numpy.empty_like(a)
new_a.fill(255)
new_a[(r != a.max(axis=2)) | (r <= 125) | (g >= 70) | (b >= 110), 1:] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` there is your rgb array, isn't it?

```
for row in a:
    for px in row:
        px[0] = 255 - px[0]
        px[1] = 255 - px[1]
        px[2] = 255 - px[2]
```

or more generally:

```
for row in a:
    for px in row:
        n = modify(px)
        px[0] = n[0]
        px[1] = n[1]
        px[2] = n[2]
```