# Filling a numpy array using an arbitrary function

Tags: python, numpy

Normally, the summation of a function would be done like this in python

```
fsum = 0
for k in range(1, N+1):
    fsum += f(k)
```

Where `f` is some function.

The whole point of using `numpy` is to [vectorize everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768354/368599). In this case, the loop is going to be slow for very large `N`. How do I go about using `numpy` to fill a `numpy array` using a function `f` (that may take multiple arguments)?

Comment: Your example does not fit the title.  You are not filling an array, you are summing a function over a simple range of values.  In `numpy` you 'vectorize' by expressing the problem in terms of functions that use fast compiled code.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for pointing that out (+1). My (incorrect) assumption was that I can fill a `numpy` array by doing something like this: `narray = np.array(f, range)`. I'll leave the title as-is for anyone who stumbles on this with the same assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I've expanded your code to the minimum required to actually execute it, including choose a specific f(k):

```
import numpy as np

def f(k):
    return(np.log(k**2))

N=8
fsum = 0
for k in range(1, N+1):
    fsum += f(k)

print fsum
```

Which gives and answer of 21.209.  Now let's do the same thing but vectorized.  Note the function f(k) is the same.

```
import numpy as np

def f(k):
    return(np.log(k**2))

N=8
k = np.array(range(1, N+1))
print np.sum(f(k))
```

And this gives the same answer.  The key difference is that I have defined a numpy array to contain the inputs you iterate over in your for loop.  That is:

```
k = np.array(range(1, N+1))
```

Which, if you want to be even more efficient, can be simplified to:

```
k = np.arange(1, N+1)
```

Since f(k) was already written to use numpy math functions it was already vectorized.  Then instead of using a loop containing a += operation, I instead used the numpy.sum vectorized function on f(k):

```
print np.sum(f(k))
```

As you can see the result is more concise, and for large arrays it will be significantly faster too.

Comment: Much better explanation than the answer in the link I gave. Thanks!